# Which style is applied?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have two different CSS (one from a WordPress theme)

```
body .portfolio-content h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

and one from a WordPress extension (TimelineJS)

```
.tl-timeline h2 {
  font-size: 46px;
}
```

Which `font-size` will be applied to an element `<h2>` place into a `<div class="tl-timeline">`, itself placed into a `<div class="portfolio-content">` and why?

```
<div class="portfolio-content">
    <div class="tl-timeline">
        <h2>One h2 title</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems that it is 18px, but I would like to set it to 46px with from the 2nd CSS. How can I do this without modifying the CSS (they come from WordPress theme and extension) ?

Thanks

Comment: Without modifying CSS? Do you want to set it through JS?

Comment: Add your css after the first two, and in that create a rule: `.portfolio-content .tl-timeline h2 {font-size: 46px}`

Comment: Can't you just test this and see?

Comment: Or quick and dirty: `font-size: 18px !important;`

Answer (score 0):

If it is 18px try to add a custom line of css in your child theme style.css

```
body .portfolio-content .tl-timeline h2 {
  font-size: 46px;
}
```